# Can't make a class hide by clicking on the toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".info").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).siblings('.conteudo').slideDown(500);
        $(this).parents().siblings().children('.conteudo').slideUp(450);
        $(this).parents().siblings().children('.info').removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<div>
  <div class="info nome"></div>
  <div class="conteudo texto">conteudo</div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="info nome"></div>
  <div class="conteudo ls">
    <a href="/">adfsdf</a>
    <a href="/">adfsdf</a>
    <a href="/">adfsdf</a>
    <a href="/">adfsdf</a>
    <a href="/">adfsdf</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="info nome"></div>
  <div class="conteudo texto">this is where the content goes</div>
</div>
```

I want to add the possibility to hide `.conteudo` when the same `.info` class is clicked on. Right now whenever one `.info` class is clicked on, its `.conteudo` class shows up and hides when the next/previous `.info` class is clicked, so I'd like to make it that people can hide the `.conteudo` class by clicking twice on its `.info` class without messing the show/hide effect it already has.

I'm new to jQuery and I'm trying to learn this stuff so please be nice. I've looked for help about this but I couldn't find anything actually helpful. Thank you so much and sorry if I'm wasting your time.

Comment: By the way, the word for what you're building here is an accordion. There exists a jQueryUI widget for that, if you're interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a check for if you clicked on the active one, and slide up if so:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".info").click(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $(this).siblings('.conteudo').slideUp(450);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $(this).siblings('.conteudo').slideDown(500);
            $(this).parents().siblings().children('.conteudo').slideUp(450);
        $(this).parents().siblings().children('.info').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="info nome">toggle</div>
  <div class="conteudo texto">conteudo</div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="info nome">toggle</div>
  <div class="conteudo ls">
    <a href="/">adfsdf</a>
    <a href="/">adfsdf</a>
    <a href="/">adfsdf</a>
    <a href="/">adfsdf</a>
    <a href="/">adfsdf</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="info nome">toggle</div>
  <div class="conteudo texto">this is where the content goes</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is even simpler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".info").on("click", function(){
    var info = $(this);
    if (info.hasClass('active')) {
      info.removeClass('active').siblings('.conteudo').slideUp(450);
    } else {
      info.addClass('active').siblings('.conteudo').slideDown(500);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with `hasClass` and revert your actions.

```js
$(function(){
    $(".info").click(function(){
        if( !$(this).hasClass('active') ) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $(this).siblings('.conteudo').slideDown(500);
            $(this).parents().siblings().children('.conteudo').slideUp(450);
            $(this).parents().siblings().children('.info').removeClass('active');
        }
        else {
          $(this).removeClass('active');
          $(this).siblings('.conteudo').slideUp(500);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="info nome">INFO</div>
  <div class="conteudo texto">conteudo</div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="info nome">INFO</div>
  <div class="conteudo ls">
    <a href="/">adfsdf</a>
    <a href="/">adfsdf</a>
    <a href="/">adfsdf</a>
    <a href="/">adfsdf</a>
    <a href="/">adfsdf</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="info nome">INFO</div>
  <div class="conteudo texto">this is where the content goes</div>
</div>
```